# Why is the first element in an array always 0?

Tags: arrays

I'm wondering where the thought of the first element in an array being zero came from. Why is it not 1? I've gotten used to the fact that it is zero, but cannot come up with a reason for the first element to be zero.

Comment: [Why numbering should start from zero](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF)

Comment: Also, not all languages/systems *do* use 0 as the first element. Your question assumes that this is universal, which it isn't.

Comment: One has to ask: Why does numbering in our daily life start at 1? Does it start at 1 for every culture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is a block of sequential memory.  If the beginning of the array is at memory address `x`, then the first element is at address `x+0`, the second is at `x+sizeof(arraytype)`, the third is at `x+2*sizeof(arraytype)`, etc.

Comment: Exactly, I was just about to write the same thing, - it is due to an implementation detail that zero is being used as the first element.

Answer (score 2):

Came from C language and Assembler.  A pointer and array are interchangeable

```
char* a;
a[0] is equivalent to *(a+0)
```